# Who is the box art artist for Monster Maker 3 (Super Famicom)?

Tags: snes, monster-maker-3

This is a highly specific question, and perhaps somewhat unlikely to find an answer, but here's hoping...

Does anyone know who did the box art for the game Monster Maker III (or モンスターメーカー３ if you will)? This was a game made by company SOFEL, who created a few games for the Famicom, Super Famicom and GameBoy. As far as I know, this game was only ever released in Japan for the Super Famicom (known here as Super Nintendo Entertainment System or SNES). It is not particularly rare or expensive, so perhaps someone has this in their possession and can find a reference in the manual. Trying to find references online, or scans of the manual, has yielded no success. Maybe someone recognizes the style simply on sight.

[image: Monster Maker 3 box art front]

Box front shot taken from [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/).

Comment: Please explain the downvote, so I can decide whether the question is valid or not. A mute downvote doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: I think you should be able to see the reason for the close votes. This is voted offtopic as it has nothing to do with playing the game or something that's conducive to playing the game (such as hardware issues). I didn't downvote this by the way, neither did I upvote, as I think it's a good question, just offtopic. Maybe the guys in the chat can give you an answer?

Comment: @JamesJiao Yeah, I'm not entirely certain of this either. I can see how it's a borderline case. But I honestly wouldn't really know where else to put it. We'll see. Didn't think it had a great chance of being answered anyway. I did go through the FAQ to make sure it wasn't outright against the rules and guidelines for questions (not very active here, but I'm not new to StackExchange either).

Comment: This sounds more like trivia than anything else, but we do allow lore questions.  Not sure if we allow things like identify the artist, but it seems to fall close to lore-type questions.  I think this can be objectively answered, although the usefulness of it is in question.

Comment: You could also try posting this at Reddit's [/r/tipofmytongue](http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/), [/r/askgames](http://www.reddit.com/r/askgames), [/r/gamenostalgia](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamenostalgia) and [/r/retrogames](http://www.reddit.com/r/retrogames) subreddits.

Comment: @galacticninja Very good references! I'll see about asking there. Maybe this could be closed, then. I'll leave that decision to those with the necessary privileges. If an answer does pop up eventually, I'll upvote and accept. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The illustrator is Kugatsu Hime (九月姫).

Comment: "Princess September"... You're my hero! Absolutely wonderful!